# Does ASP.NET Custom Errors override the actual HTTP response code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

If I were to specify a page for redirect using the ASP.NET Custom Errors feature, would my application still spit out the HTTP status code for that particular error?

For example if had a line in my `web.config` that had all Internal Server Errors redirect to `Errors/500.aspx` and then I encountered a 500 error, I would then be redirected to my custom `Errors/500.aspx` page. Will my application still respond with a HTTP 500 at any point in this exchange?

I'm just curious...

Comment: To make ASP.NET behave correctly with errors is infuriating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because your browser would interpret that 500 response as an error and show you *it's* error.  Instead, it probably responds with one of the redirect status codes to send you to the defined error page.